# How to get back Arsclassica's default section style

Tags: titlesec, classicthesis, arsclassica

I'm using the `arsclassica` option of the `classicthesis` package. I changed the section's format so that they are aligned to the left on odd pages and to the right on even ones.

In  doing so I lost the arsclassica's default style for section titles. How can I get it back?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% \titleformat{name=\section, page=even}{\raggedleft\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{}{}
% \titleformat{name=\section, page=odd}{\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{}{}
% --------------------
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

before

[image]

after

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, did you have a look into file `classicthesis-arsclassica.sty` for the definition for comand `\section`? Here it comes:

```
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
  {\textsc%
    {\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}%
  }%
  {1em}%
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps}
```

So you only need to redefine the `\titleformat` for even pages like:

```
\titleformat{name=\section, page=even}%
  {\raggedleft\normalfont\Large\sffamily}% <============================
  {\textsc%
    {\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}%
  }%
  {1em}%
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps}
```

For odd pages you can use the standard format.

So please see the following corrected MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext} % <================================== for dummy text
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

%\usepackage{titlesec} % <=================================== already loaded
\titleformat{name=\section, page=even}%
  {\raggedleft\normalfont\Large\sffamily}% <============================
  {\textsc%
    {\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}%
  }%
  {1em}%
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps}


\begin{document}
\section{Test for odd page}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\section{Test for even page}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]